# Examine whether the function $f(x, y)$ is continuous on $\Bbb R^2$ or not

Tags: multivariable-calculus, continuity

> Given,
>
> $f: \Bbb R^2 \rightarrow \Bbb R,$
>
> $$f(x, y) := |\frac y {x^2}| e^{-|\frac y {x^2}|}, x \neq 0, y \in \Bbb R,$$
>
> $$f(x, y) := 0, x = 0,$$
>
> I have to decide whether the function is continuous on $\Bbb R^2$ or not.

I'm still new to multivariable calculus, so I'm not sure how to work with the critical values yet, but I gave it a try.

Assume $f(x, y)$ would be continuous on $\Bbb R^2.$ Then, $f(x, y)$ must be continuous in $f(x, y) = 0,$ which means that, given any sequence $(x, y)_{_n \in \Bbb N},$

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} (x, y)_n = 0 \Rightarrow \lim_{n\to \infty} f(x, y)_n = f(\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}, 0)$$

Now, in my opinion, this can't be true.

When $\lim_{n\to \infty} (x, y)_n = 0$, then $|\frac y {x^2}|$ converges to $1,$ since $x^2$ becomes (at a certain point) smaller than $1,$ such that $x^2$ converges much faster to $0$ than $y$ does. Therefore, the fraction becomes bigger. Transfering this result to $e^{-|\frac y {x^2}|},$ this term should simply converge to $1 \over e$, and so does the whole expression. On the other hand, putting in $y = 0$ doesn't give the same result, therefore, the function can't be continious on $\Bbb R^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**. We have
$$
\lim_{(x,x^2)\to (0,0)}f(x,y)=\lim_{(x,x^2)\to (0,0)}\left(\left|\frac y {x^2}\right| e^{\large -\left|\frac y {x^2}\right|}\right)_{y=x^2}=e^{-1}
$$ which violates
$$
\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}f(x,y)=f(0,0)=0.
$$

Comment: But that's exactly what I wrote above, isn't it? :-)

Comment: @Julian Right! I did not read the end of your message! But I think it is clearer to write it as I did above:)

Comment: Haha, yeah, you're right. :-) Thank you very much!

Comment: @Julian You are welcome!